# Relation between stochastic independence and functional independence?

Tags: probability, independence

We know if two variables are functionally independent then there will be stochastic independence as well. Can any one give me an example when the converse is not true i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are independent (stochastic) but not functionally independent?

Comment: How is functionally independence between random variables defined?

Comment: X is not a function of Y and Y is not a function of X as well. That is functional independence. @StefanHansen

Comment: Take $X=Y=1$, for example.

Answer (score 3):

> We know if two variables are functionally independent then there will
>   be stochastic independence as well.

This is wrong.  If $X, Y$ have a bivariate normal distribution woth correlation $\rho=\frac12$, they are clearly functionally independent (there do not exist some function $f$ such that $f(X,Y)$ is almost surely a constant, but they are not independent.  Even with the reformulation that *if two variables are stochastically independent, they will be functionally independent* you must be careful, it will not be true if they have zero variance, for instance (two almost surely constant random variables are independent!)

As for your question I have just given the example. Takeaway: You need to be more careful with your definitions.

Comment: +1 for the interesting definition of "functionally independent". A reference for further reading would be welcome.

Comment: @Galen: You can compare with the definition given here:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/functional-independence.75805/   Also  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110763/intuition-behind-functional-dependence